# How to use ORDER BY and comparing more than 2 columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

So I'm having some problems with an SQL Query, or maybe rather deciding on if I could solve this issue faster in an PHP While loop. See I have a small table with **4 teams**, and each team will be assigned a rank based on each teams total points in GOLF,FOOTBALL and Miniature GOLF. The points in the different games: 8 to the first placed team, then 6->4->2 to the other teams depending on score in each game. Then I convert the total score to a ranking number. Here is an example:

[image]

MY question and my problem is:
That I don't want two teams to share rank. As you can see team_id 3 and 2 have the same amount of total points, therefor they have rank 3 together. I want to order this table after the team with the highest value in any of the games that have been played. SO! Team 2 has 8 points in one of the games, which is higher then team 3 highest score. So the rank_13 should look like this instead:

[image]

I tried to make a query that compares two teams with the same rank_12 point, but I don't know how to compare on 3 columns. Also tried to print the first table out in PHP and then alter the displayed values depending on highest value in the 3 columns, even more confusing. Am I unclear somehow? Please give me a comment.

Comment: You can do multiple order by something as order by rank_12,{another_col} ... But in your case if rank is same you need to decide using which column you need to make a sort.

Comment: I want to first fort by rank_12, if two are eqaul sort by the one that has the highest value in golf, football or minigolf.

Comment: You can do order by rank_12 asc, golf_points desc, football_points desc, mini_points desc

Comment: try `order by rank_12,max(col1,col2,col3)`

Comment: A normalised design would make this problem trivially easy to solve.

Comment: Please share your design thoughts. I would be glad to change the structure

Comment: team_id, game_id, points

Comment: I see your point, maybe I should change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to order several column seperated by commas and use GREATEST() to find maximum points and compare like this

```
......order by rank_12 ASC,GREATEST(golf_points,football_points,mini_points)DESC
```

Comment: No I don't get that to work: check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'football_points,mini_points.
With several values in Max function

Comment: Well now it seem to work actually, I will do some more testing before I mark it, thank you any way :)